# Different Context Menus for Enabled and Disabled TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a TextBox. When it is enabled, I get a good context Menu having Cut, Copy and Paste.

Now when TextBox is disabled, I want to have a different context menu. I mean that contextMenu should have only 1 option i.e. Copy.

I have tried to Wrap the TextBox inside a Grid and then I applied a Context Menu on that Grid. But it does not make difference. Is there any other way?

Comment: Those who mark this question Negative, please care to comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a hidden label (contain textbox text) above the textbox.

if your textbox is disabled un-hide the label and show whatever you want with pop-up menu.

When you enable the textbox, hide the label

**EDIT:**

For example (I using static positions to make it easy), If you have a textbox with this coordinate (0, 0, 100, 100), Add a hidden (un-visible) label above him with same coordinate (0, 0, 100, 100).

Contact pop-up menu to the label with all options you want (such as Copy, Export, whatever).

Now, if the user clicks on the textbox he should receive all textbox options, but if the textbox is disabled the user should click on the label and not on the textbox, therefore he should receive what you decide with the pop-up menu.

**Pay attention** I don't remember if you can scroll a label or not. Anyway you can put the label inside a layout and it's will be like a textbox (with scroll...)

Comment: Thanks. I have sorted out the fixes and then used your trick which works well.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [IsReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.isreadonly(v=VS.95).Aspx) property of the TextBox instead of disabling it. This will handle the context menu, meaning the only enabled option will be Copy.

Making the TextBox disabled will tell the user that it cannot interact with it, if it's readonly it has a slightly different visual style indicating that it still can be interacted with.

**Edit**

If you're in a MVVM scenario and want dynamic items in the ContextMenu simply bind the ItemsSource of the ContextMenu to a collection that you can modify as needed.

**Edit 2**

To fix this from xaml only you can add all the items to the same ContextMenu and create a style for MenuItem that will hide them based on the IsEnabled property of the parent:

```
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem" x:Key="menuItemStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

To show the ContextMenu on disabled items you can use: `ContextMenuService.ShowOnDisabled="True"`

Comment: I cannot use the IsReadOnly. I have to make it Disabled. As I am also dealing with Drag-Drop operations.

Comment: Also, I just gave an example of Copy. But I want to have different options for disabled textBox.

Comment: @Vishal Maybe you should elaborate on what you're exactly trying to do because Adrian is right: if it is disabled, you should not interact with it. There must be a more user-friendly way to achieve what you want.

Comment: @PatriceGahide OK, I have a treeView. I set it's ItemTemplate to Textbox. I want my users to rename the items. So, when He/she right click on that Item, I want the textBox to be enabled for renaming. I cannot use ReadOnly TextBox as Users will also be given a facility to Dra and Drop the treeView Items. If I set TextBox to ReadOnly, then I may not be able to drag them.

Comment: I don't need the items to be dynamically created. I just want the options : When Enabled : Cut/Copy/Paste & When Disabled : Add/Rename/Delete

Comment: @Vishal See my edit, I've added a way to use this from xaml only, that can be used in your scenario.

Comment: But how do WPF know which items to show and which items to hide?

Comment: Hello. I get binding errors. So, All the items in menu are visible all the time.